# How does a capacitor get charged while the charger circuit isn't closed?

Tags: electric-circuits, charge, capacitance, batteries

a capacitor is a very known device in circuits that can be used as a short-time battery by charging it using another source, 
but how does it really get charged?
if the plates of the capacitor don't touch, it means that there is air between them (or any other material with high resistance) which means there is no way for electricity to pass through this material, it's really puzzling.

Comment: This question does not show any research effort.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it shows no research effort.

Comment: I think you guys are being too hard on the poster. This may seem obvious to us, but I've never seen it explained clearly in a textbook.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A voltage source makes electrons leave one of the plates of the capacitor (and so makes that plate positive). Electrons pass through the voltage source and are deposited on the other plate (and so making it negative).
No charges pass through the insulator between the parallel plates.

Comment: but as a follow up question, if the plates are put away from each other will it also get charged?

Comment: If you meant pulled away from each other then they would but if the same voltage source was used not as much charge would be stored.  The capacitance of the capacitor would have decreased.

Comment: oh it makes more sense now